# Rails json data type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql

I have a model with a field of type json

```
class Bank < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Quite simply I wish to be able to record the balances of various currencies in the currencies field. i.e.

```
Bank.first.update(currencies: {usd => 100}) #usd=100
Bank.first.currencies #{"usd" => "100"}
```

This works for a single currency however when I wish to add a second it overwrites the first:

```
Bank.first.update(currencies: {gbp => 1000}) #gbp=1000
Bank.first.currencies #{"gbp" => "1000"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save current currencies in variable:

```
=> cur = Bank.first.currencies
```

Update current curriencies with new currency:

```
=> Bank.first.update(currencies: cur.merge({ gbp => 1000 }))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
bank = Bank.first
bank.currencies = bank.currencies.merge {"gbp" => "1000"}
bank.save
```

Comment: You must use `( )` or SyntaxError is raised.